# Fable convert string to enum without match or lookup

Tags: f#, fable-f#

In Fsharp you can convert string to enum link follows:

```
type Langs = 
    | En = 0
    | Afr = 1

let tryLang str =
    try 
        Enum.Parse(typedefof<Langs>, str) :?> Langs
    with e ->
        Langs.En
```

In fable I get the following error:

```
error FABLE: Cannot resolve System.Enum.Parse
```

Is there a way to do the conversion without having to use a match statement or some other lookup?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: No, fable cannot do this.

Fable can compile most of F#, but very little of .Net BCL (Base Class Library).

You might, however, be interested in [StringEnum attribute](https://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#stringenum-attribute) to solve your particular problem.